# Web scraping VIVINO using Python

Tags: python

I have made a script for scraping all red wines on Vivinos page for price, ratings, country, grapes etc. However when I use the below code I get everything I need until I reach around 2000 wines. After this, the loop just repeats it self. As I can see there are many more red wines avaliable on Vivino, I would kindly ask for any help regarding getting as many wines as possible with the stated variables.

```
enter code herimport requests
import pandas as pd
import urllib, json
import urllib.request, json
import time

def scrape():
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame()
    results = []
print("Retrieved Wines:")
print("---", 0)

for i in range(500):
    r = requests.get("https://www.vivino.com/api/explore/explore",
    params = {
    "min_rating":"1",
    "order":"asc",
    "page": i+1,
    "price_range_max":"500",
    "price_range_min":"0",
    "wine_type_ids[]":"1"
},
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"})


    for j in range(24):
        try:
            result_list = []
            result_list.append(r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"][j]["vintage"]["name"]) #Name
            result_list.append(r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"][j]["vintage"]["year"]) #Year
            result_list.append(r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"][j]["vintage"]["wine"]['region']["country"]["name"]) #country
            result_list.append(r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"][j]["vintage"]["wine"]["winery"]["name"]) #wine_yard
            result_list.append(r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"][j]["vintage"]["wine"]["region"]["name"]) #region
            result_list.append(r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"][j]["vintage"]["statistics"]["ratings_average"]) #Rating
            result_list.append(r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"][j]["vintage"]["statistics"]["ratings_count"]) #reviews
            result_list.append(r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"][j]["price"]["amount"]) #price
            result_list.append(r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"][j]["vintage"]["wine"]["vintage_type"]) #vintage_type

            number_of_grapes_in_wine = (int(len(r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"][j]["vintage"]["wine"]["style"]["grapes"])))
            for grape in range(number_of_grapes_in_wine):
                result_list.append(r.json()["explore_vintage"]["matches"][j]["vintage"]["wine"]["style"]["grapes"][grape]["name"]) #Grape(s)
        except:
            pass

        results.append(result_list)

    print("-- ",len(results))

df_results = pd.DataFrame(results)
df_results.to_excel("Red_wine_Data3.xlsx")
```

scrape()
e